# Bitmap getpixel returns always a negative number

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb

I've loaded an image as a bitmap from device storage and wanted to retrieve the pixels rgb from it , but the `getPixel(x,y)` method always returns a large negative number

i found similar questions i even found the the same code as an answer but it doesn't work for me the bitmap is mutable

**the code**

```
inputBitmap=inputBitmap.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
int pixel;
byte r, g, b;
pixel =inputBitmap.getPixel(j, i);
Log.e("pixel","j "+j+" i "+i+" "+pixel);
r = (byte)Color.red(pixel);
g = (byte)Color.green(pixel);
b = (byte)Color.blue(pixel);
Log.e("COLOR","\n"+"Red : "+r+"\n"+"Green : "+g+"\n"+"Blue : "+b);
```

**Logcat**

```
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR:
    Red : -1
    Green : -1
    Blue : -1
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -1
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: 
    Red : -1
    Green : -1
    Blue : -1
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -1
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: 
    Red : -1
    Green : -1
    Blue : -1
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -460552
05-28 13:02:51.335 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: 
    Red : -8
    Green : -8
    Blue : -8
05-28 13:02:51.336 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -1381654
05-28 13:02:51.336 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: 
    Red : -22
    Green : -22
    Blue : -22
05-28 13:02:51.336 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -1315861
05-28 13:02:51.336 20379-20379/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: 
    Red : -21
    Green : -21
    Blue : -21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

solved but still weird ,on the following log , i had randomly positive/negative signs but the absolute values are correct, all i had to do is keep their absolute value and it Worked

`````
05-28 14:35:21.225 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -16743306
05-28 14:35:21.225 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: Red : 0
    Green : -124
    Blue : 118
05-28 14:35:21.649 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -13920116
05-28 14:35:21.649 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: Red : 43
    Green : -104
    Blue : -116
05-28 14:35:22.057 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/pixel:  -48066684
05-28 14:35:22.057 15064-15064/pfe.steganography E/COLOR: Red : 34
    Green : -113
    Blue : -124 ````
`````

Comment: Which is wrong. The problem: colour have values from 0 to 255, but `byte` is a signed value, from -128 to 127. BTW the `Color` class uses `int`, and you should use `gerRed()`? or `getRGB()`. You are using strange logic. Beware: the values you get are RGB in sRGB. New phones have larger space, you you may get negative numbers.

Comment: yes i changed it to `int` but still the `Bitmap.getPixel()` returned negative but it's absolute value is always accurate when i tested it

Comment: BTW `Color.red(pixel);` seems very wrong. You should really understand the cause, not just guessing "absolute works". `getPixel` return an `Color` (as integer). it is not a problem to be negative. In fact you should forget about interpreting the value of Colour (but if you look the documentation, which tell you what is the meaning of every bit). Handle it as `Colour`, not as `int`. Forget about numeric value.

Comment: BTW solid colours must be negative.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i actually needed the values to be positive to create a new color from rgb to put them in a new bitmap ,i had issues writing down the wanted bitmap cause of those values that's why , thank you for your answer ! i'll document myself more about this topic

Comment: The value is irrelevant. Positive or negative is also irrelevant. It has no meaning. Forget such value. Use the channels (R,G,B), but when you use them combined, interpret the value as a obscure code (and no relative meaning between numbers). Positive numbers are semi-transparent colours (or full transparent colour). But we have the class `Color` to hide such details.